# How do I stop useEffect from repeating over and over again

Tags: reactjs, axios, rerender

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export const GetData = (url) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(url);
        setData(response.data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    };
    getData();
    return () => {};
  }, [data]);

  return {
    data,
  };
};
```

I am using the component above for multiple multiple components. My problem is that the request keeps repeating over and over again. I want to stop it from repeating. The only time it should repeat is when "data" changes.
I tried using axios' cancel token but that did not work. I also tried stopping it using intervals (maybe I did it incorrectly. I don't know). The code below shows one of the components that I am using the GetData component. Hopefully this helps.

````
import React from 'react';
import { Card, Table, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

import { DeleteData, GetData } from '../../../api';
import { useGlobalContext } from '../../../context';

const SectionTable = ({ url }) => {
  const { setIsEdit, getId } = useGlobalContext();
  const { data } = GetData(url);

  return (
    <>
      <Card style={{ maxHeight: '500px', overflowY: 'scroll' }}>
        <Card.Body>
          <Table striped responsive hover>
            <thead>
              <th>Section Level</th>
              <th>Section Name</th>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {data.map((section) => {
                return (
                  <tr key={section.id}>
                    <td>{section.section_level}</td>
                    <td>{section.section_name}</td>
                    <td>
                      <Button
                        variant='warning'
                        onClick={() => {
                          getId(section.id);
                          setIsEdit(true);
                        }}>
                        Edit
                      </Button>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <Button
                        variant='danger'
                        onClick={() => DeleteData(section.id)}>
                        Delete
                      </Button>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                );
              })}
            </tbody>
          </Table>
        </Card.Body>
      </Card>
    </>
  );
};

export default SectionTable;
```**strong text**
````

Comment: Don't you mean when `url` changes..?

Comment: No I need data to change because I want the data to update real-time. 

Note: Yes I know I should just use websockets but I was advised that it would be too much.

Comment: Why is web sockets too much if it gets done exactly what you want?

Comment: Then you'll need to use e.g. a timer to keep reloading data. https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/master/docs/useInterval.md is a good hook for that.

Comment: Tried it but it keeps repeating every single second. Might as well use websockets

Answer (score 0):

listing data as a dependency means that the effect runs after every render that was triggered by a change in `data`. Instead depend on url:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(url);
        setData(response.data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    };
    getData();
    return () => {};
  }, [url]);
```

Comment: I need data to be the one that updates because I want it to be in real-time 
I could just websocket but I was told not to.

Comment: So you want new data to be fetched when you just received new data?

Comment: No I want the new data to be fetched whenever that new data is available. i.e. whenever data changes.

Comment: The dependency you're specifying has to do with the data in your react app, if you want to get notified about new data being available, web sockets sounds like a good choice.